# How can I redirect to dynamic page on notification according the notification

Tags: php, yii, notifications

I'm making a notification future in Yii using PHP with a dynamic data from database. this is come of my CSS code

```
<style>
#notification_count 
{
padding: 3px 7px 3px 7px;
background: #cc0000;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 9px;
-moz-border-radius: 9px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 9px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -11px;
font-size: 11px;
}
</style>
```

and this is  HTML

```
<div id="notificationContainer" style="width:300px">
                        <div id="notificationTitle" style="padding: 8px; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; color:#000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;">Notifications</div>

                        <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications item-test"  style="padding: 8px; color:#000000; overflow-y:auto;max-height:300px" >
                            <?php
                            if($count == 0){
                                $notif = '<div align="center" style="font-style:italic;color:#d3d3d3; padding-bottom:5px;">No Notification</div>';
                                echo $notif;
                            }else{
                                for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
                                    $notif_query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT NOTIF_DETAIL FROM (SELECT NOTIF_DETAIL, ROWNUM AS RN FROM (SELECT NOTIF_DETAIL FROM TRN_NOTIFICATION WHERE RECIPIENT = '$user' AND SENDER != '$user' AND UNREAD = 'UNREAD' ORDER BY NOTIF_ID DESC)WHERE ROWNUM <= $i)WHERE RN = $i")->queryScalar();
                                    $date = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT UPDATE_DATE FROM (SELECT UPDATE_DATE, ROWNUM AS RN FROM (SELECT UPDATE_DATE FROM TRN_NOTIFICATION WHERE RECIPIENT = '$user' AND SENDER != '$user' AND UNREAD = 'UNREAD' ORDER BY NOTIF_ID DESC)WHERE ROWNUM <= $i) WHERE RN = $i")->queryScalar();
                                    $notif_value = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT NOTIF_ID FROM (SELECT NOTIF_ID, ROWNUM AS RN FROM (SELECT NOTIF_ID FROM TRN_NOTIFICATION WHERE RECIPIENT = '$user' AND SENDER != '$user' AND UNREAD = 'UNREAD' ORDER BY NOTIF_ID DESC)WHERE ROWNUM <= $i) WHERE RN = $i")->queryScalar();

                                    $notif = '<div>'.$notif_query.'</div>'; ?>
                                        <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;" name="notificationValue" id="notificationValue" value="<?php echo $notif_value; ?>" method="POST"><?php echo $notif; ?><div align="right" style="color:grey; font-style:italic;"><?php echo $date; ?></div></div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>      
                        </div>

                        <div id="notificationFooter" style="background-color: #e9eaed; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; padding: 8px; font-size: 12px; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;"><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/index.php?r=TrnNotification/admin">See All</a></div>
                    </div>
```

and this is my JavaScript that redirect to my controller

```
$(function(){
 $('#notificationValue').on('click',function(){
    window.location.href = "<?php echo Yii::app()->baseurl; ?>/index.php?r=TrnNotification/notif";
 });
});
```

this allows me to have a notification if there's someone commend or change something that related to users. But the problem is I cant send the value of selected notification so that the value can send to my controller and change the flag of each notification to be marked as "read" and didn't display in notification list anymore.

this is some code that i try to get selected value in my controller

```
public function actionNotif(){
    $value = $_POST['notificationValue'];

    if(isset($value)){
        $this->redirect(array('TrnProjectIT/admin'));
    }
}
```

I always get an error that says `undefined index : notificationValue`. How can I pass  my dynamic value of notification to the controller so that I can redirect to a specific page based on selected notification from user? I might think there's a problem in my looping and passing my value but I don't have any solution. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You always get an error that says `undefined index : notificationValue` simply becouse you're not sending anything to the server.

- You have a div with `method`, `name` and `value` attributes that are **not allowed** in `<div>`.

Simply use a `href` redirect and pass the parameter that you want to the server in GET. So remove the `<div name="notificationValue">` and the Javascript and use this instead:

```
<a href="<?= Yii::app()->baseurl ?>/index.php?r=TrnNotification/notif&notificationValue=<?= $notif_value; ?>"><?= echo $date; ?></a>
```

and server side controller:

```
public function actionNotif(){
    if(isset($_GET['notificationValue'])){
        $this->redirect('TrnProjectIT/admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, sorry for my late reply. this codes works but my view is not as I want. Because of using `<a href>` and thing that I want to display is one full sentence, it didn't fit on my column. for example: total sentence length is `500px` and according to my query. my column `max-width` is `300px`. it keeps displaying 500px with scroll bar. what I need is it will be fit on the column so it will be `300px` then it got a break and continue with the rest `200px`. Sorry for my bad english, did u get what I mean?

Comment: Not completely. Want you a div with that dimensions instead an <a href>?

Comment: Yes, some-kind like that, so it have a static width for my notification container. If I use `<a href>`, the full sentence will be in one row only even though the sentence is longer than my box width